# RestSharp Json return from Identity

Tags: c#, rest, xamarin, post, restsharp

I am trying to view the JSON response in the output window however I can only seem to get an output if the username doesn't already exist, but if the username does exist then the JSON response will not display however it will display in Postman.

Here is the response I get in postman and the output window of Visual Studio if the username is accepted...

```
{
    "id": 12,
    "email": "chad@chad.com",
    "roles": []
}
```

However, if the username is already taken I get this response only in Postman, which I believe is generated from Identity...

```
[
    {
        "code": "DuplicateUserName",
        "description": "User name 'Chad35' is already taken."
    }
]

var client = new RestClient("http://192.168.1.20:5000");

var user = new CreateUserDto
        {
            Username = usernameEntry.Text,
            Password = passwordEntry.Text,
            Email = emailEntry.Text
        };

var signUpSucceeded = AreDetailsValid(user);

if (signUpSucceeded)
{
    var request = new RestRequest("api/users", Method.POST);
    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
    request.OnBeforeDeserialization = resp => { resp.ContentType = "application/json"; };
    request.AddJsonBody(user);

    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

    var content = response.Content;

    Debug.WriteLine(content);
}
```

Any ideas on how to overcome this... the one main difference between the two responses are the inclusion of the identity response being enclosed in square brackets.

Comment: I'd try using Wireshark or something similar to capture the actual request being sent and compare it to the Postman request for any differences

Comment: Jason - that is a clever idea... I will give that a try.

Comment: Jason- I checked it out on Wireshark and there is absolutely no difference that I can tell.

Comment: No idea.  Perhaps RestSharp is doing something with the response - I don't use that package so I can't tell you.  Either see if there is a way to view the raw response, or switch to a plain HttpClient instead

Comment: Jason- Thank you for your help. it ended up being RestSharp that was the problem. I switched to HttpClient and that did the trick.